# sh: node: command not found - when npm install command on AWS Instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2

I want to run a node app on AWS EC2 instance. I installed node through this official method by AWS Doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html.

Then, I can view the version of node and npm but when I give the command npm install on the node app folder , it starts to install a few dependencies and then it fails. with the error as

```
> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /var/apps/backend-master/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

sh: node: command not found
npm WARN mysql_db@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN mysql_db@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! core-js@2.6.11 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-16T19_28_07_911Z-debug.log
```

Do let me know if there is an additional step to do or if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: May you paste the last lines of `/root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-16T19_28_07_911Z-debug.log`? It may reveal what went wrong.

Comment: Did step 5 of the guide you linked work?

Comment: Yes , I did. It printed the version number

Comment: I've found this question because I faced the same problem. I didn't follow amazon's instruction, but my installation was pretty much the same. I've installed node through nvm, but couldn't install aws-sdk which failed on postinstall phase (but `npm i axios` run successfully though). I've double checked PATH variable and everything were ok... I've made new ec2 instance and performed installation from your amazon link. everything work just fine right now ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. npm version: 8.1.0, node version: 17.0.1